# Do I need to consider the Client OS when testing websites?

Tags: testing

I have a general web question.

**To be able to test my website on various browsers properly, do I need to consider the operating system too?** Is it enough to just test my site on FireFox 3, for example, or do I need to test it on FireFox 3 on Windows, Mac, and Linux? Is it possible for a given browser version to behave differently on different platforms?

Comment: WHat do you mean by "Test"?  What features are you testing?

Comment: S.Lott, I'm refering to it in a general sense - layout and behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say yes, well platform at least.

Some other differences between Mac OS X and Windows (don't forget Linux)

- different gamma levels
- font rendering
- fonts installed by default
- size of the chrome

I realise testing on all OS's can be difficult, so make use of [BrowserShots.org](http://browsershots.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the link alex. This will be of great help. It seems that the differences are mostly on the layout/rendering of the sites. Would you know if the Javascript engine would differ too?

Comment: @oninea There probably are differences, but the most obvious are in renderings and OS specific defaults.

Comment: +1; he's right. and don't just consider OS on desktop and laptops (Win vs Mac), mobile devices too have a huge factor in browsing websites, they have OS too, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. In fact, I believe firefox on Linux and on Windows actually do display things slightly differently (as for some reason their default font is different)

To be completely thorough, yes - you should be testing on all OSes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, not only is it *possible*, it's *absolutely true*. Firefox renders quite differently on, say, Ubuntu than it does on Windows or OS X. While the OS itself is not, strictly speaking, an element, every browser--even the same family--is different for each OS.

Comment: Adam, what about javascript behavior?